# Correct use of preposition in this sentence

Tags: prepositions

> For Eritrea, a lasting settlement to the prolonged conflict on the Horn of Africa will constitute a major milestone, one that has come 25 years after it gained independence from Ethiopia in 1993, following a prolonged guerrilla war.

is it correct to use conflict on the horns? according to oxford advanced learners conflict over sth is correct,

Comment: Take care with capital letters. Remember, every sentence and every proper noun starts with a capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

There are different meanings.

"A conflict over the Horn of Africa" means "a fight for control of that region"

"A conflict on the Horn of Africa" means "a fight in that region".

> Two men had a conflict over a girl.  The conflict was on the street

In the case of the war in Eritrea, it was about some of the border regions, not for the control of the whole Horn of Africa, so "A war on the Horn of Africa" is the correct meaning.

Comment: With the Horn of Africa in OP's context, my preference would be for ***in***, not ***on*** (as reflected by [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+the+Horn+of+Africa%2Cin+the+Horn+of+Africa&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20the%20Horn%20of%20Africa%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20Horn%20of%20Africa%3B%2Cc0)). Interestingly, exactly the same "stylistic choice" applies with *[fighting] **in/on** the street* again shows an overwhelming preference for ***in***.